# jtoken string type conversion

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

I am attempting to save a JObject string value as a decimal to then insert into a SQL database.

```
insertWellData.Parameters.Add("@Latitude", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = entityParams["Latitude"].ToObject<decimal>();
```

The latitude value is either null or a string i.e. 49.4567
I have an if statement above this sorting out the null values so I know that they are not the issue.

```
if (entityParams["Longitude"].Type == JTokenType.Null)
```

When I run my code I immediately get the error

```
System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'
```

Is this caused by the Latitude value being undefined at the start of the code run, or is there something else that I am missing?

Comment: So is it the `ToObject<decimal>` code that's failing? If so, the ADO.NET part isn't as relevant. It would help if you could provide a [mcve] so that we could test this for ourselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this may help, you could try to parse the value to decimal before you use it with TryParse.

TryParse, returns a bool value indicates whether the conversion succeeded, in addition the out part gives you the result of the conversion. So next code will prevent to work with an invalid result:

```
    if (!Decimal.TryParse(entityParams["Latitude"].ToString(Formatting.None), out decimal Latitud))
    { 
    // if .TryParse fails - set the value for "Latitud" to 0.0
        Latitud = 0.0m;
    }
```

doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.tryparse?view=net-5.0